# AC-DC converter (230V - 5V) supply for microcontroller to control outlet

Tags: microcontroller, relay, solid-state-relay, ac-dc

I have built a circuit using a PBO-3-S5, AC-DC circuit and applied some necessary components. iIn the description and when testing the circuit I get a 4.8V output voltage which should be enough to drive a Rasperry pi zero.

But the problem that have occurred for me is the part which should be able to switch on and off the outlet.

I have tried using transistors by using two in parallel of each other and controlling them with the micro controller but did not get them to turn on. My second idea is to use a solid state relay, but they are rather bulky and expensive. My question is, are there any other switches that can be used for power outlets with control of a micro controller such as a rasberry pi? 
The picture shows how my circuit should look like some how.[image]

Comment: SSRs, regular relays and triacs are the only real options plus, with  triacs you need to isolate the micro from the gate drive circuit. Not a simple or safe project for a novice.

Comment: Yes so the SSR seems to be the best option by what i can find to buy. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13015 
Im thinking of using this one. But overall, do you have any comments on the circuit, something i should think about or havent thought about?

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried using transistors by puting two in parallel of each other and controlling them with the microcontroller but didn't get them to turn on.

You are lucky that you and your equipment survived that. It was a very dangerous and foolish experiment because you had violated the insulation between your micro-controller and the mains.

You must use an isolation device properly rated for your voltage and current of your load. Typically for 230 V supply you look for isolation > 1000 V. Apply some safety margin to your current as well.

[image]

Solid-state relays are available in small packages. You must ensure adequate safety distance between the control and output terminals.